# Inserting 1D array to 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, pass-by-reference

Can we directly insert a 1D array to a 2D array?

For example I have this code:

```
void insert(int[]data , int**collection)
{
collection[1] = data
}
int main()
{
int data[2]= {1,3}
int collection[2][2];
insert(data,&collection);
}
```

Will this work?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: If you define your arrays differently, you can do this.

Comment: `int **` is not a 2D array. It may be used to manage data in a "2d-like" fashion. But it is still something totally different than `int [2][2]`. Oh, and you cannot do array-assignments in C (unless it is part of a struct assignment), only pointer assignments.

Comment: @HAL9000 how do you make a call by reference in c for 2D arrays?

Comment: @HAL9000 "Oh, and you cannot do array-assignments in C (unless it is part of a struct assignment), only pointer assignments" Do you mean this line of code is wrong?"collection[1] = data"?

Comment: This may help explain why your code does not work: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot insert a `1D` array to `2D` array the way you are doing. Use `memcpy` to copy the elements of `1D` array to `2D` array, like this:

```
memcpy(collection[1], data, 2 * sizeof(int));
```

this will copy the `2` integer elements of `data` array to `collection[1]`.

Besides, a couple of problems in your code. Lets discuss them:

**First:**

```
insert(data,&collection);
            ^
```

You don't need to pass the address of `collection`. Note that, an array, when used in an expression, will convert to pointer to its first element (there are few exceptions to this rule). That means, when you pass `collection`, it will convert to type `int (*)[2]`. Just do:

```
insert(data, collection);
```

**Second:**

```
void insert(int[]data , int**collection)
```

`int[]data` is wrong. The first parameter of `insert()` should be `int data[2]` or `int data[]`, both are equivalent to `int * data`. You can use either of them.

The second argument to `insert()` is `collection` array which is a `2D` array of integers. When you pass it to `insert()`, it will decay to pointer whose type is `int (*)[2]`. The type of second parameter of `insert()` is `int **` which is not compatible with the argument that you are passing to `insert()` function. The second parameter of `insert()` function should be `int collection[2][2]` or `int collection[][2]`, both are equivalent to `int (*collection)[2]`.

Putting these altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW 2
#define COL 2

void insert(int data[ROW], int collection[ROW][COL]) {
    //for demonstration purpose, copying elements of data array 
    //to all elements (1D array) of collection array.
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        memcpy(collection[i], data, COL * sizeof(int));
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int data[COL] = {1, 3};
    int collection[ROW][COL];

    insert(data, collection);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            printf("collection[%d][%d] : %d ", i, j, collection[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
collection[0][0] : 1 collection[0][1] : 3 
collection[1][0] : 1 collection[1][1] : 3
```